# More efficient query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how do they do a query with only one textbox in the page, but the current text in the text box can be used as a parameter for the query.
I'm currently using the query below but I don't think I'm getting the desired results, is there anything wrong with my query?

```
$result1=query_database("SELECT * FROM prod_table WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '$cuts%' OR PRODUCT LIKE '$cuts%' OR P_DESC LIKE '$cuts%' ", "onstor", $link);

?>


<?php

if(mysql_num_rows($result1)==0){

}else{
```

How to do this kind of query better.

Comment: What results are you getting vs what are you expecting? Also consider using binds since doing straight variable substation is very dangerous and buggy

Comment: What result do you get and what result do you expect to get?

Comment: I should get all the results beginning with 'a' when I type in 'a'. But I think I'm only getting one or two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use % before $cut and escape this query is fine

```
 $result1=query_database("SELECT * FROM prod_table WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '%$cuts%' OR PRODUCT LIKE '%$cuts%' OR P_DESC LIKE '%$cuts%' ", "onstor", $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

if   `query_database` is not defined by you

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prod_table WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '$cuts%' OR PRODUCT LIKE '$cuts%' OR P_DESC LIKE '$cuts%' ", "onstor", $link);
```

Comment: I defined query_database on the connection file.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes for each of the 3 fields, CATEGORY,PRODUCT,P_DESC and it should run much faster.

Are you sure that LIKE '$cuts%' is correct?
I believe that it should be LIKE '%$cuts%'. In the way that you have written it, it will only find the products which start with the value of the $cuts